# Filter rows when column not equal

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a filter but can not seem to get it to work.

When column "number" is the same but the column "spec" is not, I want it to filter out the rest.

---

**Example**:

number   name   spec

100    cola   1
100    cola   1

200    pepsi   3
200    pepsi   3
200    pepsi   4

300    fanta   1
300    fanta   1
300    fanta   1

400    zingo   9
400    zingo   7

---

**I want it to come out like this.**

number   name   spec

200    pepsi   3
200    pepsi   3
200    pepsi   4

400    zingo   9
400    zingo   7

---

**My code:**

```
Select partno, partdsc1, G08T1.g08huqty
from L62T1
join G08T1 on G08T1.shortl62=L62T1.shortl62
```

Comment: Your code seems to have nothing to do with the question.  Do you have one table or multiple tables?  What are the columns really called?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your *question* is that you can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.number = t.number and t2.spec <> t.spec
             );
```

If your "table" is really a query, then you can use a CTE to define an alias for it.

However, with a query, it might be more efficient to use window functions:

```
with cte as (
      <your query here>
     )
select cte.*
from (select cte.*,
             min(spec) over (partition by number) as min_spec,
             max(spec) over (partition by number) as max_spec
      from cte
     ) cte
where min_spec <> max_spec;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.* from t t1 
    inner join (select distinct * from t) t2  
    on t1.number = t2.number 
    and t1.name = t2.name 
    and t1.spec <> t2.spec
```

Comment: Does this answer the question?